# Magento or Shopify which is best for integration with Python or which provide best APIs for Python

Tags: python, magento, flask, e-commerce, shopify

I am a Python developer. I wanted to create some online shopping stores which will be fully customized, Database will Mysql, Redis for caching, mail-gun for mailing, AWS hosting and  Theme may be customized. I am confused in both platforms Magento and Shopify. Please Help Which have the best integration with python.

Answer (score 0):

Yes Rehan is correct to go with the magento framework

Answer (score -1):

Magento is better than Shopify for large scale stores with huge catalog and magento is an open-source platform that gives user significantly greater adaptability as he can transform it the way you need to.

Magento definitely has the advantage when it comes to capabilities and flexibility. While Shopify is hosted by the company, and Magento is a self-hosted solution can be Host on AWS or any other hosting service.

As frontend themes in Shopify are proprietary, they don’t allow lot of tweaking. Beyond changing colors and font, Shopify users are not able to fully customize themes, creating a possible issue for store branding while Magento themes come quite customize-able though with a developer expertise needed in most cases.

You can probably get better answers here: https://www.quora.com/What-are-the-pros-and-cons-of-Magento-vs-Shopify

Comment: Thank You Rehan, for diverting my mind to Magento. one more thing can I operate all Magento APIs with Python ? or I need to work with PHP..?

Comment: Yes @JB.py you could connect magento APIs from Python directly.

Comment: This answer is ill-informed and full of opinion without much basis in reality. FYI.